# query to pivot data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

i have a data in table like this:

```
=================================
  name  |  study  |  avg_scores
=================================
  alfa     c#         75
  beta     c#         70
  alfa     php        85
  beta     php        90
```

and i want the result like this :

```
===========================
 name |   c#    |   php   
===========================
 alfa     75        85     
 beta     70        90
```

so how to make a query in mysql to get those results?
Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: Do you know the number of study subjects at design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select first.name,
  max(if(first.study = 'c#', first.avg_scores, NULL)) as 'c#',
  max(if(first.study = 'php', first.avg_scores, NULL)) as php
from `table` first 
join `table` second
  on first.name = second.name
group by first.name
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c61c/1

For dynamic ones:

```
set @sql = NULL;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
     'max(if(first.study = ''',
      study, ''', first.avg_scores, NULL)) as ',
      study
    )
  ) into @sql
from `table`;

SET @sql = concat('select first.name,
                  ', @sql, ' 
                   from `table` first
                   join `table` second
                   on first.name = second.name
                   group by first.name');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49c560/2

Comment: it's works 
. then what if type of study is not limited. 
for example: there will be a study => 'VB6', 'xml', 'json' and others

Comment: error:  #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Comment: have you escaped c# or either removed `#`? also you need to reaarange the query if your column name is different, check the fiddle..

Comment: sorry, my error because the data in the column study two syllables. 
for example: "junior php", "junior c". and i have error => "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c,max(if(first.study = 'junior php', first.avg_scores, NULL)) as junior php ' at line 2: prepare stmt from @sql"

Comment: so then have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be:

```
select n.name, c.avg_scores as C_AVG, p.avg_scores as PHP_AVG from `table` n join `table` c on n.name=c.name and c.study="c#" join `table` p on n.name=p.name and p.study="php" group by n.name
```

UPDATE: If the type of study doesn't matter, try this:

```
select name, study, avg_scores from `table` group by name, study
```

If will not return by column, but it's working well.

Comment: @user3747046 Sorry, fixed the answer. Make sure to replace `table` with your table name.

Comment: always no result sir :(

Comment: It's working on sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c61c/14/0

and

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c61c/14/1

I don't have any idea why it's not working for you, I tested it on MySQL right now and it works.